# Loading a video with opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I am a beginner in Python and OpenCV and am currently facing a problem. I tried to load a video but then I am getting an error.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

car_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('project11.xml')
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('Crop_DownResolution.mp4')

def car_detection():
    while (cap.isOpened()):
        _ , img = cap.read()
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        cars = car_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.2, 5)
        cv2.line(img,(120,260),(380,260),(0,0,255),5)

        for (x,y,w,h) in cars:
            cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
            roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
            roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]

            if (y+h)>260:
                collision_warming = 1
                print('warning')
            else:
                collision_warning = 0

        cv2.imshow('img',img)
        k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
        if k == 27:
            break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But when I run the code, I got this error when the video finishes.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\littl\Desktop\Presentation\Project Video.py", line 33, in 
<module>
car_detection()
File "C:\Users\littl\Desktop\Presentation\Project Video.py", line 10, in 
car_detection
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: C:\projects\opencv- 
python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:11111: error: (-215) scn == 3 || 
scn == 4 in function cv::cvtColor
```

Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: before accessing an image, test whether it was loaded correctly once after cap.read()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is probably because the video file is not in the working directory. I would recommend you give the full path to the video.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('path/to/where/video/is/Crop_DownResolution.mp4')
```

Comment: I've tried this but this doesn't seem to solve the problem. When I run the code, the video runs perfectly fine, but when the video reaches the end time, it gives the error as above

Comment: Try to print your _ variable and check if it is true. It is probably because your video is passing an empty frame. What you can try doing is putting that part of the code inside a try-except block